# How to create, append and read a txt file with flash as3

Tags: flash, actionscript

First off, I am kind of new to Flash and only really know really basic stuff.

(Scenario) I have made a local game in Flash CS3 Professional for my Advanced Higher Computing project for school which is almost completely glitch free.  But my teacher says it needs a file handling feature, such as a high score feature in it to make it AH standard.  I want to make a simple high score feature where it takes the final score, asks the user to input their name, and add it to a .txt file.  Since the computers at my school are very limited, I cannot use programs like Adobe AIR or PHP or anything like that so I need it to be simple.

(Question) So I really need a full tutorial (where to put the coding, layout and everything) to:

1. Check if there is an existing .txt file called (for example) "High Score.txt"
2. If there is, load it.
3. If not, create a .txt file called (for example) "High Score.txt" to the desktop.
4. Take the users input and place it with their final score after it.
5. (Optional but not required) Arrange the scores in order of highest to lowest or display the top 5.

I will really appreciate it if someone will help me.

Thank you.

Watson.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure what you're asking is impossible due to security restraints. SWFs generally can't modify local files since it would open up all sorts of vulnerabilities. I'm sure AIR has ways around this with local DBs and such, and if your game was hosted on a web server you could use a simple (insecure) PHP proxy to write to a text file, but you already mentioned that those options are out.

An alternative approach which will have the same result:

Use [flash.net.SharedObject](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html) (check the example code) to store your high scores locally. This is a "Flash Cookie" which can be used to store limited amounts of data (Objects, Arrays, etc) on an individual computer.